# Stopping a windows service leaves a process running

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a set of windows services that I recently moved to a new box.  These are .net applications (v4.0) that were installed using the installutil application.  What is happening now with these applications is that whey they are stopped remotely or via Services manager UI the process associated with that service does not terminate.  I realize some delay may be expected but even after a very long wait the services still appear to be running when I look via the task manager.  When the service is then started back up second instance of the exe process is started.

Seeing as this is a new box I am wondering if there could be something else running on the box that is preventing this from occurring.

This does not reproduce on the old machine, not does it seem to be happening with other services on this box.

Any thoughts on how I might track down what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your .NET code needs to be fixed. It's not handling service stop requests properly. I know it "worked fine" on your old server, but I'm sticking to my story. :P

First, check your Event Logs for unhandled .NET exceptions. If that doesn't get you anywhere, then go to your code.

You probably have a method in your code that looks something like

`protected override void OnStop() { ... }`

I would start adding some logging to the code right around there and try to figure out where it's failing.